# XML XPath SelectSingleNode issues

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectsinglenode

I am trying to select certain nodes inside of childnodes of the main document.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//RECORD");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{           
     Console.WriteLine("Time: " + nodes[i].SelectSingleNode("//content2").InnerText);
}
```

What this ends up doing, is that everything single content2 node, has the same value, yet in the XmlDocument, the content2 value for each 'Record' is incremented.

If I look through the NodeList, each content2 node is incremented from 1 to 32 for example.

Why does SelectSingleNode return the same node? How do I make it select it from the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the "//" from your XPATH string. This will look inside of the selected XML instead of the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using //content2 in the XPATH for nodes[i].SelectSingleNode.  // in XPATH means look at all instances at any level.  You should do an XPATH of //RECORD/content2 then loop those nodes.

Comment: I agree, however, there are a multitude of nodes that I am going to need in each record, not just the one.

Comment: How can I just look internally? Do I omit the "//"?

Comment: Removing the // will grab the first node encountered in the set.  So if you're looping selecting single node, you're still always going to grab the first one.  For what it looks like you're doing, you would want to grab all the nodes using SelectNodes using the XPATH without // and then loop that result set.

Comment: I am going to grab the first one of EACH Record. Instead of the first one in the XML Document.